# Empty <p> element not actually empty? Ascii Control characters?

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

Using JavaScript, I'm going through an array of objects. If the object has 1 or more values that are not null or empty, a `<p>` element is created and then appended to the container element.

```
var tempElem = document.createElement("P");

if( item.valueOne !== '' )
    tempElem.innerHTML += item.valueOne;
if( item.valueTwo !== '' )
    tempElem.innerHTML += item.valueTwo;

if( tempElem.innerHTML !== '' )
    containerElem.appendChild(tempElem);
```

The above does filter out most empty entries, however a few are somehow making it through to the page.
On chrome, it shows exactly `<p></p>`
I've done some analyzing, and before the last if-statement...

```
typeof tempElem.innerHTML = string
tempElem.innerHTML.length = 4
tempElem.innerHTML.charCodeAt(0) = 1
tempElem.innerHTML.charCodeAt(1) = 1
tempElem.innerHTML.charCodeAt(2) = 1
tempElem.innerHTML.charCodeAt(3) = 1
tempElem.innerHTML.charCodeAt(4) = NaN
```

I'm quite lost on this one. The actual data is in json and for these particular values, I'm seeing `key:""`. Which is exactly the same as the ones that are being filtered just fine.

I know I can check the values in javascript before creating any kind of dom element, but I'd like to know what's causing this and how to fix it directly.

Comment: According to [ascii-code.com](http://www.ascii-code.com/): 1 is a Start of Header character. Have you tried utilizing [String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)?

Comment: Yup. All my data has that called on it before it gets saved actually. I just tested it out and `trim()` does not take off ascii 1.

Comment: Avoid `innerHTML` (it's non-standard, is expensive, and has side-effects). Consider using `textContent` instead. It might also solve this issue you're having.

Comment: Expensive? I know of the other two negatives, but never heard about it being expensive before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was due to my usage of the `.trim()` method.
`STRING.trim()` does not remove characters such as `x00` (Start of Header), `x01` (Start of Text), etc.
If present in an otherwise empty string however, these characters will still pass a `===""` check.

For my specific purposes, this simple regex fixes the issue:
`str.match(/[^\x00-\x20\x7F]/)`
(will return true if at least 1 non space or 'empty' character exists)